# modify HTTP status code of proxy result in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy

I have a nginx reverse proxy serving a web application. This web app returns a `302` redirect in some cases and I can't change it. However, for some reasons I need to change this returned status to be `301`.

I tried

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 302 =301;
```

but obviously this the `=301` part as the new location. So what I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 302 =301 $PROXY_HEADER_LOCATION;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header fields of the upstream server are accessible through `$upstream_http_*`

So this worked for me:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 302 =301 $upstream_http_location;
```